# Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class Exception in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Forgive me since I am rookie to hibernate and other answers on similar questions didn't quite fix this issue(I am sure my issue is quite basic). I am trying to have a OneToMany and ManyToOne mapping in my persistence classes.
I have following tables:

```
city (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255),
)

pincode (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    pincode VARCHAR(6),
    city_id INT FOREIGN KEY fk_city_id ON city(id)
)

area (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    pincode_id INT FOREIGN KEY fk_pincode_id ON pincode(id)
)
```

The following persistence class I wrote:
For City:

```
@Table(name="city")
@Entity
City {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
}
```

For PinCode:

```
@Table(name="pincode")
@Entity
PinCode {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "pincode")
    private String pinCode;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
    private City city;  //Multiple pincodes may be mapped to one city

    //One pincode may have multiple areas
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "pincode_mapping")
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
    private List<Area> area;
}
```

For Area:

```
@Entity
Area {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = PinCode.class)
    @Column(name = "pincode_id")
    private PinCode pinCode;    //Multiple areas may be mapped to one pincode

}
```

Facing the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with
name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-resources.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.mycompany.model.PinCode.area[com.mycompany.model.Area]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define your join column in the many to one annotation in your Area entity:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = PinCode.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "pincode_id", nullable = false)
```

plus, in your Pincode entity you should indicate the correct field in the `mappedBy` property:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "pincode")
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you have something like this in your hibernate configuration

```
<mapping class="com.mycompany.model.PinCode" />
```

Or, if you are using java config

```
.addAnnotatedClass(PinCode.class);
```

Make sure taht all your `@Entity` classes are declared as mapping classes, or configure it to auto-scan

Comment: Thanks. This was also missing, apart from the annotation error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use `mappedBy` wrong: you add there the column name in the database however it has to be the property name in the `Area` entity by the `PinCode` is mapped:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "pinCode")
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
private List<Area> area;
```

And the JavaDoc of `mappedBy` tells you the same:

> The **field** that owns the relationship. Required unless the relationship is unidirectional.